# Why is the LaTeX in my comment unreadable?

Tags: support, comments, mathjax

Below a Question in Aviation SE I put a comment containing mathematical formulae. I had prepared the formulae using http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php. But it didn't become readable. Why?
I paste below the results so you can understand:

> `I return on my second question. In order to have real solutions (\frac{T}{W}-G)^{2}-\frac{4*Cdo}{\pi ARe}\geq 0 . Then for simplicity of reasoning I define (\frac{T}{W}-G)=x and \frac{4*Cdo}{\pi ARe}=b . So the condition becomes x^{2}-b\geq 0 , but this (second grade) inequation is verified in both following zones: x\geq \sqrt{b} and also x\leq \left - \sqrt{b} \right i.e. \frac{T}{W}-G\geq 2\ast \ \sqrt{\frac{CD0}{\pi \ast AR\ast e}} and also \frac{T}{W}-G\leq-2\ast \ \sqrt{\frac{CD0}{\pi \ast AR\ast e}} . But Raymer exclude the second one, I don’t understand why.`

Comment: Can you link to the post / comment? Aviation has mathjax enabled - did you delimit it correctly to make it identifiable as mathjax?

Comment: MathJax expressions should be delimited with `$...$` (or `$$...$$` for displayed equations). See, e.g., [this fairly comprehensive guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020) from [math.se].

Comment: @Oded There seem to be a couple comments on [this answer](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/27403).

Answer (score 1):

> But it didn't became something readable. Why?

Because you didn't enclose them with `$$...$$` as required.

I have edited your [comments](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27369/about-climb-if-we-use-t-w-as-input-the-second-grade-equation-yields-two-soluti/27403#comment68015_27403) on the answer to include those.

Comment: thank you very much Oded : it just have not be transformed $$ x\leq -\sqrt{b} $$

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, but I don't know why this has happened. The box around the equation shows it is recognized as mathjax, but it doesn't render it correctly. BTW - you will see that the comments have balooned - they are much too big now.

Comment: Also the previous my comment under the same question has ".... 1) Two different solutions    ............ 2) Two coincident solutions : when....... 3) No solutions : when ..... ", but it happen that you put "2)" and "3)" inside the formulae and now I'm not allowed to edit it

Comment: Just using single dollar-signs (`$..$`) would make the expressions _inline_, and cut down on the vertical space they take up. (Also, for the `x \leq \left -\sqrt{b} \right` expression, the `\left` and `\right` commands expect an extensible delimiter as an argument, which are absent. A relevant [tex.se] [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77589).)

Comment: @arjafi - thanks for that, I didn't realize that delimiting `$$` and `$` would be so different. Updated comments.